# R - Saving image within function is not loading

Tags: r, function, savestate

This below code can be loaded with the `SoStuck` object existing:

```
Im <- c(1,2,3,4)
Stuck <- c(6,7,8,9)
SoStuck <- data.frame(Im, Stuck)
save.image("image.RData")
```

I then quit out of this session and start another. I do this:

`load("image.RData")`

It works:

```
SoStuck
   Im  Stuck
1  1     6
2  2     7
3  3     8
4  4     9
```

However, if I do this:

```
myfunction <- function()
{
  Im <- c(1,2,3,4)
  Stuck <- c(6,7,8,9)
  SoStuck <- data.frame(Im, Stuck)
  save.image("image.RData")
}
myfunction()
```

Restarting R, loading and then calling does not find the object:

```
load("image.RData")
SoStuck
Error: object 'SoStuck' not found
```

I have also tried `return(save.image("image.RData"))` in that loop and get the same error.

Anyone know what I need to change to load the file if it was saved inside a function? Thanks.

Comment: Your function does save an image of the environment of the function call, but that is the global environment and it doesn't have SoStack in it. The only function that I know of that does something like this is `ecdf`. It stores data inside a function environment gives it its own class, and assigns a call attribute to the returned function. One then needs to create a function with data, and assign it a name. There are methods designed for function-objects of class ecdf. (AND it's not certified for long-term storage of results.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation of `save.image`, "save.image() is just a short-cut for ‘save my current workspace’, i.e., save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE), file = ".RData", envir = .GlobalEnv)."

So to get your function to work, you can modify your code like this:

```
myfunction <- function()
{
  Im <- c(1,2,3,4)
  Stuck <- c(6,7,8,9)
  SoStuck <- data.frame(Im, Stuck)
  save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE), file = "image.RData", envir = 
  environment())
}
myfunction()

load("image.RData")
```